# awk matching against two files and print desired output

Tags: awk, multiple-columns, rows

awk gurus, I tried a lot of awk hints here but not able to solve this with required output I am trying to get almost 4 days, maybe I am missing  something to solve this puzzle in the following similar `awk` query, but no success.

Tried following variations:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$5;print;next}{for(i in a)if(a[i]==$1)print $2,i}'
 awk -F '[| ]+' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$4]=$1 OFS $2; next}
       $1 in a{print $1, a[$1]}' file2 file1

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} {n=0;for(i in a){if(substr($0,22,3)~i) { n=1}  } } n' file2 file
```

INPUT FILE1 for matching:

```
T ASDasd  2 AAAAA BBBBB Device 
T as9df7  2 CCCCC QQQQQ Device 
T a987fa  3 EEEEE FFFFF Device 
T asd4f6  3 88888 TTTTT Device
T 56sd4f  3 HHHHH SSSSS Device
T 56sd4f  3 00000 UUUUU Device
T 56sd4f  3 77777 45454 Device
```

INPUT FILE2 for matching against FILE1:

```
AAAAA INFO CAR
XXXXX INFO CAR
CCCCC INFO TRUCK
DDDDD INFO TRUCK
GGGGG INFO TRAIN
TTTTT INFO TRAIN
RRRRR INFO BMW
SSSSS INFO VOLVO
WWWWW INFO VOLVO
EEEEE INFO SYS
PPPPP INFO SYS
00000 INFO RIVER
77777 INFO RIVER
```

OUTPUT should be:

```
T ASDasd  2 AAAAA INFO CAR Device
T as9df7  2 CCCCC INFO TRUCK Device
T a987fa  3 EEEEE INFO SYS Device
T asd4f6  3 TTTTT INFO TRAIN Device
T 56sd4f  3 SSSSS INFO VOLVO Device
T 56sd4f  3 00000 INFO RIVER Device
T 56sd4f  3 77777 INFO RIVER Device
```

It matches file2 (1st column) against file1 (4th + 5th column) and comparing with printing output of names with any matched data.

I am quite lost with this, still learning this `awk` to understand how to write awk query for this. have a great day to all.

```
tried this but its resulting to its not fully desired output ad not sure where to look exactly and why its otputting file2 with result info

 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;print;next}{for(i in a)if(a[i]==$8)print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 ,i}' match2 match1
AAAAA INFO CAR
XXXXX INFO CAR
CCCCC INFO TRUCK
DDDDD INFO TRUCK
GGGGG INFO TRAIN
TTTTT INFO TRAIN
RRRRR INFO BMW
SSSSS INFO VOLVO
WWWWW INFO VOLVO
EEEEE INFO SYS
PPPPP INFO SYS
00000 INFO RIVER
77777 INFO RIVER




T ASDasd 2 AAAAA
T as9df7 2 CCCCC
T a987fa 3 EEEEE
T asd4f6 3 88888
T 56sd4f 3 HHHHH
T 56sd4f 3 00000
T 56sd4f 3 77777
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} 
               {if($4 in a) $5=a[$4]; 
                else if($5 in a) {$4=$5; $5=a[$5]}}1' file2 file1

T ASDasd 2 AAAAA INFO CAR Device
T as9df7 2 CCCCC INFO TRUCK Device
T a987fa 3 EEEEE INFO SYS Device
T asd4f6 3 TTTTT INFO TRAIN Device
T 56sd4f 3 SSSSS INFO VOLVO Device
T 56sd4f 3 00000 INFO RIVER Device
T 56sd4f 3 77777 INFO RIVER Device
```

Comment: many thank you, could you recommend me some great explanatory awk books you studied ? br, ya

Comment: I haven't read it but I think "Effective awk programming" is a good book to study.  I have been using `awk` since late 80's and studied the original `The AWK Programming Language" by A., W., and K.